# Jquery onload function nprogress.js

Tags: javascript

Использую библиотеку nprogress.js как задать функцию NProgress.start() при начале загрузки страницы, и как только страница загрузилась выполнить функцию NProgress.done()?

Answer (score 0):

Примерно как-то так :

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="ссылка на nprogress.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
  <!-- запускаем start -->
  NProgress.start();

  <!-- вешаем обработчик ивента загрузки страницы --> 
  <!-- и как страница загрузится запустим done -->
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    NProgress.done();
  });
</script>

<body>
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  <!-- Комментарий -->
  <p>Первый абзац.</p>
  <p>Второй абзац.</p>
</body>

</html>
```